# How to get the Name instead of Id's in SOQL

Tags: apex, soql

I am using below query to get the records.But in the output I am getting Account Id and Conatct id. How can i get the Account Name , Contact Name instead of Id's?

```
currentRecord = [SELECT Id,Account__c,Contact__c,Country__c,Notes__c,Business__c FROM Sample_Literature_Request__c WHERE Id = :currentRecord.Id];
```

Answer (score 4):

Hi In order to get account and contact name you have to specify that particular field as well in query. For eg in your query you have to add  Account__r.name to get account name and Contact__r.name to get contact name. so finally your SOQL query will look like

```
currentRecord = [SELECT Id,Account__c,Account__r.name, Contact__c,Contact__r.name, Country__c,Notes__c,Business__c FROM Sample_Literature_Request__c WHERE Id = :currentRecord.Id];
```

For more reference please check out [salesforce docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/05/basic-soql-relationship-queries.html).